# Redirecting old url to Nginx with param

Tags: nginx

I have an old URL structure like this `archives.php?l=e` and I moved it to a new structure `archives/e`

I'm trying to 301 redirect all the old urls, but I have run into troubles. This is what I'm currently doing but it's not working.

```
location ^~ /list.php {
    rewrite /archives/$1/ permanent;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and I have to say Nginx has some nice magic for this. Using `arg_l` solved it. Somehow it creates a variable for each param.

```
location ^~ /archives.php {
    rewrite ^/archives.php$ /archives/$arg_l? permanent;
}
```